# How use prototypical inheritance in controllers in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, prototype

I need make one Super Function inherit the this of other function and make this other function inherit the methods from the Super Function, this is possible?

Explanation:

I have my `BookingController` and I want make the `Controller` function inherit the `this.ME` property:

BookingController.js:

```
var Controller = require('../api/Controller');

function BookingController() {
 Controller.call(this);
 this.ME = 'something here';
}

BookingController.prototype = new Controller;
BookingController.constructor = BookingController;
```

Controller.js:

```
function Controller() {
    console.log(this); // EMPTY
};

Controller.prototype.myMethod = function() {
 // Should work if BookingController try to access.
}
```

But nothing happens, there is no error and the `BookingController` can't find my `myMethod` and my Controller can't my this.ME

Comment: Can you share the code that is supposed to work, but is not? It's possible that you're accessing ME / myMethod the wrong way.

Comment: yes.. one sec! @Evert

Comment: Of course it's empty, because you call the super constructor before you create the property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a bit wrong inheritance model. I suggest you to use something like

```
BookingController.prototype = Object.create(Controller.prototype);
BookingController.prototype.constructor = BookingController;
```

Comment: That's it!! I forget how to used.. but, i still cant access what i need in the controller and in the bookingcontroller! :[

Comment: working now! Thanks @Rostilav.. i forget how to inherit with Object.create and i try to search, but couldn't find!!!

Comment: While this is probably the more appropriate modern way to inherit constructor functions, the suggested change had little to do with your original problem.  As @Bergi pointed out above, the only reason this was failing for you was that you tried to examine the constructed value before you fully constructed the object.  Code that examines `this` in the middle of the constructor is, by its very nature, suspect.